# How to get change of heading angle using magnetometer

Tags: ios7, core-motion, magnetometer

I've been working on `CoreMotion Framework` from some times now. I want to get the angle corresponding to `Magnetic North`, when user having iOS device, moves in some other direction, for example I have iOS device and I've currently facing North(say, **Position A**) and than I turn and started facing East (**Position B**). Now I want the angle created in facing **Position B** corresponding to Magnetic North of the device.

This is how I'm trying now (found somewhere while googling)

```
[_motionManager startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMMagnetometerData *magnetometerData, NSError *error)
         {
             double heading = 0.0;
             double x = magnetometerData.magneticField.x;
             double y = magnetometerData.magneticField.y;
             //double z = motion.magneticField.field.z;

             if (y > 0) heading = 90.0 - atan(x/y)*180.0/M_PI;
             if (y < 0) heading = 270.0 - atan(x/y)*180.0/M_PI;
             if (y == 0 && x < 0) heading = 180.0;
             if (y == 0 && x > 0) heading = 0.0;

             NSLog(@"Heading Angle = %f",heading);

         }];
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you found? Seems to be a math issue.

Comment: @Larme any idea to eliminate this error?